# Using GET and POST to extract Edamam API?

Tags: r, edamam-api

I'm trying to extract the recipe data from Edamam API. All of my GET/POST requests fail.

I've tried to extract the data through Python, which works seamlessly but R gives "must not be NULL"

Here is the code:

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

# Store the ID and Key in variables

APP_ID = "XXXXXX"
APP_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXX"

# Note: Those are not real ID and Key,
# Replace the string with your own ones that you recieved upon registration

# Setting up the request URL
api_endpoint = "https://api.edamam.com/api/recipes/v2"

url = paste0(api_endpoint, "?app_id=", APP_ID, "&app_key=", APP_KEY)

#Defining the header (as stated in the documentation)
headers = list(
  `Content-type` = 'application/json'
)

#Defining the payload of the request (the data we actually want processed)
recipe = list(
  `mealType` = 'breakfast'
)

#Submitting a POST request
tmp <- POST(url, body = recipe, encode = "json")
tmp <- GET(url)
tmp <- httr::POST(url, body = recipe, verbose(), content_type("application/json"))

appData <- content(tmp)
```